# How to declare a method in an interface with unknown count and type arguments

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I'm trying to creating an ***`interface`*** like this:

```
public interface IProcessable<out T>
{
    T Result { get; }

    T Execute(params object[] args);
}
```

I want to have an `Execute()` method that returns `T` and *be able to accept any type of arguments*.
And I want to use it like this:

```
public class CustomProcess: IProcessable<int>
{
     public int Result { get; private set; }

     public int Execute(string customArg)
     {
         /// some codes to return int
     }
}
```

`IProcessable<int>` will force me to add an `Execute` method like this:

```
public int Execute(params object[] args)
{
    var customArg= args[0] as string;
    if (customArg!= null)   //I know that this is not so necessary for `string`
    {
        return Execute(customArg);
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

I think, I should have both methods in `CustomProcess` because of wide acceptable range of `object[]`.

Know I should ask:
Is this kind of interface is acceptable or is a kind of an anti-pattern?
Is there any better way to achieve what I want - create an interface that force class to have `Result` property and `Execute` method -?

Comment: It doesn't even make sense in the first place to have an interface for a bunch of different methods that *all have different signatures*.  That defeats the entire purpose of having an interface.  Either *ensure all of the methods can use the same signature*, or *don't use an interface* because you're getting nothing out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Servy commented, And for making a correct signature; I found my solution like this:

```
public interface IProcessInput
{
}

public interface IProcessable<in TInput, out TOutput> where TInput : IProcessInput
{
    TOutput Result { get; }

    TOutput Execute(TInput args);
}

public abstract class ProcessInput: IProcessInput
{
    protected ProcessInput(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }

    public virtual int Count { get; private set; }
}

public class WithoutProcessInput : ProcessInput
{
    public WithoutProcessInput() : base(0)
    {
    }
}
```

and so on ...